# Why can DSolve not solve this ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I wish to solve an equation for the field lines of an electric field. This is the textbook question 1.3.8(a) from D. Dubin's *Numerical and Analytical Methods for Scientists and Engineers, Using* Mathematica ([ISBN-13: 978-0471266105](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471266108)), however it is not an assigned homework problem (so feel free to give direct answers!)

### Theory

Given the potential $\phi(\rho,z)=z/(\rho^2+z^2)^{3/2}$, which has a corresponding electric field

$$\mathbf{E}(\rho,z) = {3\rho z \over(\rho^2 + z^2)^{5/2}}\mathbf{\hat{\rho}} + \left({3z^2 \over(\rho^2 + z^2)^{5/2}}-{1\over(\rho^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}\right) \mathbf{\hat{z}}$$

as given by $\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}\phi$, the equation for a field line at position $s$ is given by

$${\mathrm{d}\rho\over\mathrm{d}s}={E_\rho(\rho,z)\over|E_\rho(\rho,z)|}.$$

This is defined in my code as `ODEρ[s]`, with the magnitude $|E_\rho(\rho,z)|$ defined as `Emag[ρ[s], z[s]]`.

### *Mathematica* code

Here I am tryin to solve the equation for the $\rho$-component only.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

ODEρ[s_] = 
  ρ'[s] == (3 ρ[s] z[s])/(ρ[s]^2 + z[s]^2)^(5/2) 1/Emag[ρ[s], z[s]];

Emag[ρ[s_], z[s_]] 
  = Sqrt[((3 ρ[s] z[s])/(ρ[s]^2 + z[s]^2)^(5/2))^2 
    + ((3 z[s]^2)/(ρ[s]^2 + z[s]^2)^(5/2) - 1/(ρ[s]^2 + z[s]^2)^(3/2))^2];

DSolve[ODEρ[s], ρ[s], s]
```

which produces the following error message:

> ```
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some
> solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution
> information. >>
> ```

then replicates the `DSolve` statement without solving anything.

Could you please include in your response *what* `DSolve` is trying to do to solve the equation and *why* the error has been produced, perhaps with a quick description of why your solution works.

Comment: It looks like various of your brackets are placed incorrectly. `ODE[ρ[s_] =` seems to be missing an ending bracket. `ODEρ[s]` is incorrect too.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thank you for clarifying this! It was, unfortunately, only a simple copy/pasting error and my original _Mathematica_ code had not included this. I have updated the code provided to reflect this and it now reads the same as my original code.

Comment: I do not believe that this equation can be solved without specifying z[s], either directly or by means of a second ODE.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Is there a way to solve simultaneous ODEs in _Mathematica_? I do, in fact, have equations for the other field components!

Comment: @HarrySmith  Yes.  Check the documentation for `DSolve` and `NDSolve`.  Understand, though, that `DSolve` can solve only equations that you or I could solve, given enough time.  You may, therefore, have to use `NDSolve`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issues it raises are not  _Mathematica_ issues but a mathematical-physics ones. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: @m_goldberg I would argue that the question I asked is entirely a question about _Mathematica_. The issue I have is not with the math but with the coding: I know how to solve these ODEs by hand; I do not know how to solve them using _Mathematica_. I will, of course, allow democracy to take its course, however.

Comment: @Harry Smith: I agree with you, and have upvoted your question. Please see my updated and extended answer which shows how to find the field lines using MMA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The simple answer (Dec. 12, 15)**

After a rather long journey with Mathematica I found out that the result can be simplified drastically to fairly simple textbook wisdom.

Introducing polar coordinates {r,a} in the {$\rho$, z} plane, which means in fact working in spherical coordinates, we have the following results

Lines of equal potential

$\phi =\frac{z}{\left(\rho ^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}=\frac{\cos (a)}{r^2}=\text{const}$

$r(a)=c \sqrt{\cos (a)}$

Field lines

$\psi =\frac{z^2}{\left(\rho ^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}=\frac{\sin ^2(a)}{r}=\text{const}$

$r(a)=c \sin ^2(a)$

**Overview with simple streamplot**

As a first step, disregarding the cylindrical geometry, you could use StreamPlot:

```
ϕ[ρ_, z_] = z/(ρ^2 + z^2)^(3/2);     

fE = {-D[ϕ[ρ, z], ρ], -D[ϕ[ρ, z], z]}     
(*
{(3 z ρ)/(z^2 + ρ^2)^(5/2), (3 z^2)/(z^2 + ρ^2)^(5/2) - 1/(z^2 + ρ^2)^(3/2)} 
*)

StreamPlot[fE, {ρ, 0.1, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

**Calculation of the field lines**

In cylindrical coordinates with azimuthal symmtery the field lines $\rho (z)$ are determined by the ODE

$$d\rho/ E _\rho = dz / E _z $$

Potantial and field strength are, respectively,

```
ϕ[ρ_, z_] = z/(ρ^2 + z^2)^(3/2);

fE = -{D[ϕ[ρ, z], ρ], D[ϕ[ρ, z], z]} // 
  Simplify

(*
Out[3]= {(3 z ρ)/(z^2 + ρ^2)^(5/2), (
 2 z^2 - ρ^2)/(z^2 + ρ^2)^(5/2)}
*)
```

With the field vector fE we have the ODE

```
eq = ρ'[z] == (fE[[1]]/fE[[2]] /. ρ -> ρ[z])

(*
Out[5]= Derivative[1][ρ][z] == (3 z ρ[z])/(2 z^2 - ρ[z]^2)
*)
```

The solution is

```
ρs0 = ρ[z] /. DSolve[eq, ρ[z], z];

Length[ρs0]

(* Out[148]= 6 *)
```

It consists of 6 componentes and containes one Integration constant C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7QRe.jpg).

At z = 0 it becomes

```
Simplify[ρs0 /. z -> 0, C[1] ∈ Reals]

(*
Out[149]= {-E^C[1], E^C[1], 0, 0, 0, 0}
*)
```

Hence we have identified C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7QRe.jpg) -> Log[ρ0] and the solution becomes

```
ρs[z_, ρ0_] = ρs0 /. C[1] -> Log[ρ0];
```

An appropriate subset of these 6 solutions is the explicit equation for the field lines.

As an example the first component is

```
ρs[z, ρ0][[1]];
```

$$-\sqrt{\frac{\text{$\rho $0}^2}{3}-z^2+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \text{$\rho $0}^6+27 \text{$\rho $0}^2 z^4-18 \text{$\rho $0}^4 z^2+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 \text{$\rho $0}^4 z^8-4 \text{$\rho $0}^6 z^6}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{2 \sqrt[3]{2} \text{$\rho $0}^2 z^2}{\sqrt[3]{2 \text{$\rho $0}^6+27 \text{$\rho $0}^2 z^4-18 \text{$\rho $0}^4 z^2+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 \text{$\rho $0}^4 z^8-4 \text{$\rho $0}^6 z^6}}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \text{$\rho $0}^4}{3 \sqrt[3]{2 \text{$\rho $0}^6+27 \text{$\rho $0}^2 z^4-18 \text{$\rho $0}^4 z^2+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 \text{$\rho $0}^4 z^8-4 \text{$\rho $0}^6 z^6}}}}$$

In order for the square root appearing in the solution to stay real we must have

```
cond = - ((2 ρ0)/(3 Sqrt[3])) < z < (2 ρ0)/(3 Sqrt[3]);
```

Now we are ready to visualize the result:

A plot of the field lines is then accomplished by this function

```
pE[ρ0_] := 
 Plot[Re[Take[ρs[z, ρ0], {1, 4}]], {z, -((2 ρ0)/(3 Sqrt[3])), (
   2 ρ0)/(3 Sqrt[3])}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "Field lines (red) and equiotentials (colored)", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "ρ"}]

pE[2]
```

[image]

A plot of the equipotetial lines is

```
ϕ[ρ_, z_] = z/(ρ^2 + z^2)^(3/2);

pϕ = ContourPlot[ϕ[ρ, z], {z, -5, 5}, {ρ, -4, 4}, 
  Contours -> 15, Frame -> True , Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"z", "ρ"}]
```

[image]

A joint plot shows both line families

```
Show[{pϕ, pE[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 16}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Field lines (red) and equipotentials (colored)"]
```

[image]

Comment: Although this is certainly a useful technique for producing/viewing field lines, the problem I am hoping to solve has more to with finding a solution to the ODE rather than producing valid output through other techniques. It's more of a math excercise than a computing one, I guess.

Comment: @Harry Smith: in the meantime I have also solved the ODE and found the explicit formula for the field lines. I shall post it soon. I consider this a MMA problem, and do not agree with closing the question.